# How to change column name in SAS table?

Tags: csv, sas, multiple-columns, rename

How to change column name in SAS table?

I have a SAS table of which..one of the column name is Reporter Code. I want to change this to Reporter_Code.

What code I should write?

Comment: Please do not open a new question just to clarify your old question.  Understand the answer to your old question, or ask for clarification in the comments.  Or at _least_ reference it and/or explain more in your question here: the context from the other question would be *very* useful in getting useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure it's Reporter Code? SAS usually defaults to importing with underscores, but the label will be Reporter Code. Run a proc contents to verify the variable name vs variable label. Enterprise Guide will import with spaces in the name.
2. If you do need to rename you can use the following name literal reference

   ```
   rename 'Reporter Code'n = Reporter_Code;
   ```
3. To avoid this in the future you can set the varname option:

   ```
   options valid varname=V7;
   ```